# Why cant Routing Information Protocol RIP (distance-vector routing protocol) use Dijkstra instead of bellman ford?

Tags: routes, protocols, bgp, ospf

Hello I am learning networking and am confused about why both the interior routing protocols (RIP and OSPF) use the same algorithm to calculate the shortest path? I think I understand how they differ (RIP and OSPF) but am not clear on using a different algorithm for calculating the shortest path?

Answer (score 1):

RIP was invented a long time before OSPF and for that reason it uses a much simpler algorithm (distance vector) than OSPF (Dijkstra).

Distance vector is much simpler than Dijkstra because it only needs local information from the direct neighbors, whereas Dijkstra requires knowledge of the topology of the entire network.